# Is there a better way to make setter non primitive user defined type property?

Tags: typescript2.0

Hi I am new to typescript. I summarized my use case in the following example.

```
class Movie {
    private crew: Crew;
    private cast: Cast;
    private locations: Location;
    private movieId;

    constructor(public id: string) {
        this.movieId = id;
    }
    public getMovieId() {
        return this.moveId;
    }
    public setCrew(value: Crew){
        this.crew = value;
    }
    public getCrew() {
        return this.crew;
    }
    ...
    //other getter and setters.
};

type Crew = {
    crew_varA: string,
    crew_varB: boolean,
    crew_varC: string,
    crew_varD: boolean,
}

type Cast = {
    cast_varE: string,
    cast_varF: string,
    cast_varG: string,
}
type Location = {
    loc_varX: string,
    loc_varY: string,
    loc_varZ: string,
}
```

when I create an object of Movie, I need to call setCrew() method. But only 'crew_varA' variable has value by that time. I am not able to make a call to setCrew() method with only one variable. I need to initialize all variables with some default value which is not appropriate something like this.

```
let mv = new Movie("SpiderMan");
mv.setCrew({crew_varA: "Peter Parker", crew_varB:false, crew_varC:null, crew_varD:null}; //is there a way to set only one property of Crew and add other properties one by one based on some logic??
```

I am not sure my approach is correct or not. I appreciate your help.